# Sandia Hand passes through the steering wheel

Tags: collision

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The simulation allows the fingers to pass through the steering wheel, which makes it difficult to hold the hand while trying to turn the wheel.

[Sandia collision break through](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cg2P0eQjnwo)

In 0:35 it can be seen that there is some kind of "transparency" in the collision polygon, or it is in the hand or it is in the steering wheel, but this shows that some collision polygons are not 100% solid.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1974/sandia-hand-passes-through-the-steering-wheel/) by [Alberto Romay](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/273/alberto-romay/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-03-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There is a pull request that is addressing this issue:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/pull-request/25/polaris-raise-steering-wheel-add-collision/diff

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alberto Romay](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/273/alberto-romay/) on 2013-03-20**:
This pull request addresses the issue of the location from some vehicle parts (steering wheel raised, seat lowered) but it is not clear to me if it also addresses the issue of the fingers passing through the steering wheel like if there is no collision. Example: The hand grabs the steering wheel (surrounds it with the fingers) then the robot pulls the hand and the steering wheel gets out through the fingers. I can make another video if the last one was not clear.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-03-20**:
The steering wheel collision object is changing from a series of cylinders to a triangle mesh.